# Creating a quiz using a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm new to PHP and I need to create a quiz using a multidimensional associative array. The quiz prints out like it is supposed to but I am having two issues, one is that I am having trouble trying to make the radio buttons sticky. The other issue is that I want the key "3" to be the answer to all of the questions and I can't seem to figure out a way to count how many times "3" is checked and print out the answer. I've tried a lot of different things over the past 7 hours but nothing seems to work they way I want it to. Do you have any tips or suggestions?

```
$quiz = array(
"What does HTML stand for?" => array(
    '1' => "Home Tool Markup Language",
    '2' => "Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language",
    '3' => "Hyper Text Markup Language",
    '4' => "Hyper Text Manipulation Language",
),
"Choose the correct HTML tag for the smallest heading:" => array(
    '2' => "&lt;heading&gt;",
    '1' => "&lt;h1&gt;",
    '4' => "&lt;head&gt;",
    '3' => "&lt;h6&gt;",
),
);
foreach($quiz as $question => $answers) {
    echo $question;
    echo "<form>";
foreach($answers as $index => $answer) {
    echo "<input type='radio' name=$option>".$answer."<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modified code:

```
$quiz = array(
"What does HTML stand for?" => array(
    '1' => "Home Tool Markup Language",
    '2' => "Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language",
    '3' => "Hyper Text Markup Language",
    '4' => "Hyper Text Manipulation Language",
),
"Choose the correct HTML tag for the smallest heading:" => array(
    '2' => "&lt;heading&gt;",
    '1' => "&lt;h1&gt;",
    '4' => "&lt;head&gt;",
    '3' => "&lt;h6&gt;",
),
);

echo "<form>";
foreach($quiz as $question => $answers) {
    echo $question;
    foreach($answers as $index => $answer) {
        echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"$question\" value=\"$option\">$answer<br/>";
    }
}
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Thanks Michail, that helps a lot! You made it sticky! I think this will make it easier for me to figure out how to count the number of correct answers. I appreciate it!

Comment: Please aprove this answer in that case.